# how to prevent a user from upvoting or downvoting twice

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am working on an application which as an upvote and downvote functionality. How can i prevent a user from upvoting or downvoting more than once.

**Note**: The way is should work is that, if a particular user has already upvoted, he should not be allowed to upvote again and so on for other users.

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)  

class user_type(models.Model):
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_supplier = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.is_supplier == True:
            return User.get_email(self.user) + " - is_supplier"
        else:
            return User.get_email(self.user) + " - is_admin"
```

views.py

```
def Viewsupplier(request):
    title = "All Suppliers"
    suppliers = User.objects.filter(user_type__is_supplier=True)

    # Get the updated count:
    suppliers_votes_count = {}
    for supplier in suppliers:
        upvote_count = supplier.upvotes
        downvote_count = supplier.downvotes
        supplier_count = {supplier: {'upvote': upvote_count, 'downvote': downvote_count } }
        suppliers_votes_count.update(supplier_count)

    context = {"suppliers":suppliers, "title":title, "suppliers_votes_count": suppliers_votes_count}
    return render(request, 'core/view-suppliers.html', context)

@login_required
def upvote(request, pk):
    supplier_vote = get_object_or_404(User, id=pk)
    supplier_vote.upvotes += 1
    supplier_vote.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view-supplier'))

@login_required
def downvote(request, pk):
    supplier_vote = get_object_or_404(User, id=pk)
    supplier_vote.downvotes -= 1
    supplier_vote.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view-supplier'))
```

view-supplier.html

```
<table class="table table-borderless table-data3">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Votes</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for supplier in suppliers %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
        <td>{{supplier.email}}</td>
        <td>{{supplier.telephone}}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="table-data-feature">
                {% if supplier.email != request.user.email %}<a href="{% url 'upvote' supplier.id %}">{% endif %}
                    <button class="item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Like">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-thumb-up"></i></button>
                {% if supplier.email != request.user.email %}</a>{% endif %}
                &nbsp;<button>{{supplier.upvotes}}</button>&nbsp;
                {% if supplier.email != request.user.email %}<a href="{% url 'downvote' supplier.id %}">{% endif %}
                    <button class="item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Dislike">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-thumb-down"></i></button>
                {% if supplier.email != request.user.email %}</a>{% endif %}
                &nbsp;<button>{{supplier.downvotes}}</button>&nbsp;
            </div>                                                  
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% empty %}
        <tr><td class="text-center p-5" colspan="7"><h4>No supplier available</h4></td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That is a strange data model. Who downvotest/upvotes whom? A user himself? One user another? Are they upvoting/downvoting some kind of "posts"?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't include the models perhaps that was why it wasn't clear. users can upvote and downvote suppliers.

Comment: i edited the question, check again

Comment: That is not what's happening in your code. Your code (or proposed answer) allows a User upvote/downvote any other User or himself and allows to **get** only one upvote/downvote **in a lifetime**. So if a User A upvotes User B no one will ever upvote B again. The solution does not limit A to upvote B it forbids any other upvotes to B in general.

Comment: What is a "supplier" in your project?

Comment: i have added all other relevant codes, sorry for the confusion please.

Answer (score 1):

You should check it at the time of saving the upvote or downvote.

```
@login_required
def upvote(request, pk):
    supplier_vote = get_object_or_404(User, id=pk)
    if supplier_vote.upvotes==0:
       supplier_vote.upvotes += 1
       supplier_vote.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view-supplier'))


@login_required
def downvote(request, pk):
    supplier_vote = get_object_or_404(User, id=pk)
    if supplier_vote.downvotes==0:
       supplier_vote.downvotes -= 1
       supplier_vote.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view-supplier'))
```

Comment: the solution did not work. it only check if there is a vote on the supplier, if there is a vote on it, it doesn't add another for another user which is not supposed to be so.

Comment: The way is should work is that, if a particular user has already upvoted, he should not be allowed to upvote again.

Comment: @coderboy, i think you misplaced supplier and user table. Please provide Supplier model here.

Comment: i have added all other relevant codes, sorry for the confusion please.

Comment: @coderboy, You want : Supplier can vote to a user? Or if supplier vote to a particular user than that supplier can not vote to user again: whatever downvote/upvote. Please clarify. who will vote to whom?

Comment: yes, i want supplier to be able to vote another supplier but only once for, so when he votes for example supplier A, he can't vote again for same supplier.

Answer (score 1):

Since a User (voter) can vote on one or many Users (receivers) and there are many voters we are having an M2M relationship which has a straightforward solution in Django models:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    votes = models.ManyToManyField("self", through="UserVotes", )

class UserVotes (models.Model):
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User, null=false, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, null=false, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    is_upvote = models.BooleanField(null=false, default=true, )
    vote_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=true, null=false, )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('voter', 'receiver'), )
```

uniqueness (not more than one vote from voter per receiver) is controlled by `unique_together` constraint.

In both of the views use current user for `voter` and passed `pk` for `receiver`, e.g.:

```
@login_required
def upvote(request, pk):
    # avoid self votes
    if request.user.pk != pk:
        UserVotes.objects.create(voter=request.user.pk, receiver=pk, );
    ...
```

check votes for existence to avoid constraint check errors by querying `UserVotes` directly or via

```
request.user.votes.filter(receiver=pk, ).exists()
```